# jquery use checkbox to toggle elements in the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a `Rails 4` app where a `Trainer` has nested `Sportists` and those sportists can choose which disciplines they want to take part in, but upon doing so they have to also point out their personal and seasonal record for that discipline.

```
.field
    = f.label :m100, "100 m"
    = f.check_box :m100, :as => :boolean, :class => "m100check checkbox"
    .field.discip.m100rec.persrec
      = f.label :m100rec, "Personal record 100m"
      = f.text_field :m100rec, :placeholder => "00,00", :class => "m100recinput t0000"
    .field.discip.bestm100.bestresult
      = f.label :bestresultm100, "Seasonal record 100m"
      = f.text_field :bestresultm100, :placeholder => "00,00", :class => "bestresultm100 t0000"
```

the `haml` part looks like that and I'd like to hide `.discip` divs for as long as the user clicks on the `.checkbox` checkbox in the given `.field` div. How can that be done using jQuery?

So far I've done this and it doesn't work:

```
function show_rec () {
    $('.checkbox').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).parent('div.field > div.discip'));
        $(this).parent('div.field > div.discip').toggle();
    });
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/24Fpg/

Comment: Can you show a sample of the output HTML (a JSFiddle would be great). Also, is the content dynamically loaded?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie added a link to jsfiddle

Comment: @Xeen [is this what you're trying to do?](http://jsfiddle.net/24Fpg/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to navigate up and down the DOM in one command. You need to use `closest` (or `parent` - see note) to find the ancestor then `find` to locate the descendant:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24Fpg/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function show_rec() {
        $('.checkbox').click(function () {
            $(this).closest('div.field').find('div.discip').toggle();
        });
    }
    show_rec();
});
```

Note: If you know it is an immediate parent, you can use `parent` instead of `closest`, however `closest` is more stable across HTML changes.

If the content is ever dynamically loaded, switch to a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function show_rec() {
        $(document).on('click', '.checkbox', function () {
            $(this).closest('div.field').find('div.discip').toggle();
        });
    }
    show_rec();
});
```

This works by listening for events bubbling back to a non-changing ancestor, *then* applying a jQuery selector to the elements in that event chain, *then* calling the function *for each matching element that caused the event*.

`document` is the default fallback if there is nothing closer. Never use 'body' with delegated event handlers as `body` does not work properly with click events (because of styling).

### Update:

You can simplify to this if `show_rec` is not called by anything else (which it appears to not be):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '.checkbox', function () {
        $(this).closest('div.field').find('div.discip').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it :) will accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @Xeen what is the difference between this answer and mine? I don't see any difference in the result! :-s

Comment: @Amin Jafari: this is the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/24Fpg/9/ Your code will not handle multiple fields as it is hard-wired to the class.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/24Fpg/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(document).on('change','.checkbox',function() {
        $('.discip').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: This does not work with multiples as you hard-wired the selector: http://jsfiddle.net/24Fpg/7/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie fantastic, now I get it, +1 from me! ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no need to wrap the click handler inside of a function.
2. You should bind a `change` handler, not a `click` handler. If the user toggles the state of the checkbox via the keyboard for example, the event will not be triggered.
3. You should set the visibility of `.discip` according to the state of the checkbox. If a checkbox is checked by default, your current code will have the opposite effect of what you want (`.discip` will show when checkbox is unchecked, and be hidden when checkbox is checked).

Example:

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('.field').find('.discip').toggle( this.checked ); 
}).change();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24Fpg/8/)

Comment: All very good points, which should also be included along with the use of `closest` and `find` (the lack of which caused the actual problem).

Answer (score -1):

I do not know about Rails 4. Question looks like javascript and trying to resolve.

Your bind should not be in function if it has to be performed in first click of page load. So,

```
$('.checkbox').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).parent('div.field > div.discip'));
    $(this).parent('div.field > div.discip').toggle();
});
```

if the above didn't worked out try with parents instead of parent i.e.,

```
$(this).parents('div.....
```